# Filtering through multiple xpath elements on web page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need help scraping data from the rest of the tables off of the url listed.  The code that I have seems to go only to the first table element.  I need the SOYBEAN table data also.  Any thoughts?

```
url = "http://markets.iowafarmbureau.com/markets/fixed.php?page=egrains"

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #this opens google Chrome (Chrome can be subbed w/ firefox et al)
driver.get(url) #this will go the the actual url listed

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(div[@class="fixedpage_heading"],   "CORN")]/table[@class="homepage_quoteboard"]') 

test={}


for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[1:]:
    month = str(row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_shortmonthonly').text)
    low = str(row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_low').text)
    high = str(row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_high').text)
    test[month]=[low, high]

    print month, low, high

x=pd.DataFrame(test)
x.to_csv('test1.csv')
driver.close()
```

Comment: Your code **explicitly** filters for `CORN`. The change to remove that (again, very, _very_ explicit behavior) should be pretty obvious.

Comment: You want CORN and SOYBEANS only, or do you want all of them? if the latter, find into two parts, the first does `//td[div/@class="fixedpage_heading"`, then use those results to dig into the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the structure of both tables is similar, make a reusable function that would get you the table by label:

```
def get_table_data(driver, table_name):
    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="fixedpage_heading" and contains(., "{table_name}")]/following-sibling::table'.format(table_name=table_name))

    result = {}
    for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[1:]:
        month = str(row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_shortmonthonly').text)
        low = str(row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_low').text)
        high = str(row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_high').text)
        result[month]=[low, high]

    return result

print get_table_data(driver, 'CORN')
print get_table_data(driver, 'SOYBEANS')
```

Prints:

```
{'MAR': ['395-6', '399-0'], 'MAY': ['405-2', '405-2'], 'DEC': ['386-2', '390-0'], 'JUL': ['408-2', '409-4'], 'SEP': ['375-6', '378-0']}
{'MAR': ['1005-0', '1005-0'], 'AUG': ['1015-0', '1017-2'], 'SEP': ['1001-2', '1016-0'], 'MAY': ['1004-2', '1012-2'], 'JUL': ['1009-0', '1018-0'], 'JAN': ['999-6', '1002-6'], 'NOV': ['992-2', '1000-0']}
```

Comment: The only change I'd make here would be to stop using string substitution to generate your XPath queries and properly parameterize the filter target. Otherwise you're potentially subject to injection attacks if called with a parameter that escapes its quotes.

Comment: ...huh. Looking at selenium's implementation, it looks like it only accepts a single string as a parameter, thus not permitting bind variables' values to be passed in out-of-band. That's really, *really* bad design, since any reasonable underlying implementation will be parameterizable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, I guess there is no safe parameterization on selenium side. The OP may want either to trust the source completely, or manually check the `table_name` parameter.

Comment: Thanks All.  I figured it out before I saw your messages.  Here is how I filtered through to "SOYBEANS", "WHEAT", ect.:      table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(div[@class="fixedpage_heading"], "CHICAGO WHEAT")]/table[@class="homepage_quoteboard"][2]')